# Nextjs 13 how to implement dynamic title

Tags: next.js

I'm having trouble with implementing dynamic title with Next.js 13.

The Documents said, (https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#modifying-head)

> Warning: Currently, the <Head> export does not re-render on client-side transition using next/link, only on initial render and reloads. To work around this for <title>, you can use a client component with useEffect that updates document.title. We plan to fix this in a future release.

And then I tried with useEffect to implement dynamic title,

```js
'use client';

import { useEffect } from "react";;
import Head from 'next/head';
interface Props {
  params: {slug : string},
  searchParams: {id:string}
};

const getPost = async (id: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
  const posts = await res.json();

  return posts;
};


const Page = ({params, searchParams}: Props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const setDocumentTitle = async () => {
      const post = await getPost(params.slug);       
      document.title = post.title;
    }

    setDocumentTitle();
  }, [params.slug]);


  return (<>
      <Head>
        <title>Blog Post</title>
      </Head>
      <div>
        <h1>Blog Post</h1>
        <p>Slug: {params.slug}</p>
        <p>Id: {searchParams.id}</p>
      </div>
    </>);
};

export default Page;
```

but it is not working. still title is not changed. Is there any way?

You can reproduce it here.[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/grighth12/next-13/draft/exciting-haze?file=%2Fapp%2Fblog%2F%5Bslug%5D%2Fpage.tsx&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clacel5us0008l3ek4ubi2hlf%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fapp%252Fpage.tsx%2522%252C%2522%252Fapp%252Fblog%252F%255Bslug%255D%252Fpage.tsx%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522claceqq7701293b6mau9t18ie%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D)
The first few times seem to be working well, but the document title does not change if you continue to go back and click Go to Post1 (next/link).

Comment: With Next.js 13 `app` folder you have to use a `head.js` file to configure the `<head>` tag. See https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#step-3-migrating-nexthead.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I'm late, I hope you figured it out by now but in case someone finds it useful, check this out:
https://nextjs-discord-common-questions.joulev.dev/how-to-set-metadata-to-page-tsx-rendered-as-client-components#how-do-i-set-dynamic-metadata-that-depends-on-client-side-states

I just tried it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this pattern described, so this is somewhat simple and tangentially related to other answer but figured I'll also share.

Note that this would depend on your app structure, but I found it intuitive for to just have a dedicated title component that can sit inside the server component's `layout.tsx` `<head>`, and have a fallback listed in the metadata e.g.:

```js
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "The Default Title",
  description: 'Some interesting website description here'
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <head>
        <AppTitle />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

In this case, `<AppTitle>` can be defined in an external client component using `use client` and freely reference `window.location` once the page has been rendered in the implementing component's logic to look up the pathname, or `useParams` if you want to check for route params.

```js
'use client';

function useMyAppTitle() {
  switch(window.location.pathname) {
    //super arbitrary logic here. Not a good example but the gist of it
  }
  return result;
}

export default function AppTitle() {
  const appTitle = useMyAppTitle();

  return <title>{appTitle}</title>;
}
```

Not perfectly ideal, but this is in my opinion better than relying on `useEffect` explicitly until the NextJS API has a better alternative and just catching the first available render on client component.